# Array elements being used as indexes for arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method I have created that uses two arrays to see if a certain condition is met (this method is a test method I created to help isolate the problem, but hasn't resulted in much success). Everytime I try to run the code, I get the error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at Player.testRNumber(Player.java:150)
at GameOfSticks1.HumanVsAI(GameOfSticks1.java:79)
at GameOfSticks1.main(GameOfSticks1.java:216)
```

I am pretty new to java, and after an hour of trying to figure out what is going on, have had little success. Any help would really be appreciated. Here's the method I've been using.

```
public void testRNumber()
    {

        CurrentScore[0] = 1
            int x = CurrentScore[0]; //this equals 12 btw
            int y = CurrentScore[1]; //this equals 3 btw
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(y);
            System.out.println((ArrayOfBuckets[x][y]) + 2); 

            //everything above this comment**strong text** works fine.

            if(ArrayOfBuckets[x-1][y] == 1)
                System.out.println("Ok, so this if loop seems fine.");

        }
```

Comment: which is line 150 in your code? Is it printing 12 and 3 as x and y values when you run it? Does ArrayOfBuckets have a size that includes [x][y] and [x-1][y]?

Comment: The code you've provided won't even compile, as it's missing a semicolon after `CurrentScore[0] = 1`.  If that statement is corrected, then `x` has the value `1`, not `12` after the next statement.  Please provide the _actual_ code, the output from the `println` statements, and identify which statement is #150.

Comment: From the comment `//everything above this comment... works fine` and the fact that the exception thrown is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`, I have deduced that the problem is the line `if(ArrayOfBuckets[x-1][y]==1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your issue. Your 2D Array of Buckets is not rectangular.

2D Arrays in java do not have to be rectangular. My guess is that your array looks something like this:

```
{
    ...//Buckets 1 - 10
    {value0, value1, value2}//bucket 11 has < 4 elements.
    {value3, value4, value5, value6,...}//bucket 12 has >= 4 elements.
    //Rest of buckets
}
```

This means calling `ArrayOfBuckets[12][3]` works but calling `ArrayOfBuckets[11][3]` does not.

Answer (score 0):

As written in exception message, you are trying to access element above array. It seems your ArrayOfBuckets has a size of [any][3], so the maximum second index value is 2. Please show the rest of your code (at least arrays initialization) to be sure.

Comment: Based on the comment, I am guessing that the OP is perplexed that `ArrayOfBuckets[x][y]` works and `ArrayOfBuckets[x-1][y]` does not.